# How to write an SQL query that appends unrelated rows?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have an Oracle database, and I need a query for reporting purposes. In my table, I have action_types and the date of the action. I want to count up the number of actions in certain groups and show the most recent action of that type.

So what I want is something like

```
   Group               Number             Date
 Administrative          3              01/02/2015
 User                    1              01/03/2015  
 View-Only               2              01/04/2015
```

The problem is that each of those groups include multiple action_types, so the table itself looks like

```
 Action_Type              Date
    01                 01/02/2015
    04                 01/03/2015
    02                 01/02/2015
    03                 01/02/2015
    05                 01/03/2015
    06                 01/04/2015
```

Where actions 01, 02, 03 are all administrative actions, 04 is a user action, and 05 and 06 are view-only actions.

I can write a query that will return a single row of what I want- the number and most recent date of a single group, but I want a query that will have all the groups together, with each one having its own row as above. Is this possible?

Comment: Is there another table that says that 01, 02 and 03 are administrative etc.?

Comment: Unfortunately no, there is no table for that. These actions are only grouped for reporting purposes and these groups aren't actually used in the code or database.

Comment: OK, then what Gordon said *8-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you just want a `case` statement for grouping by:

```
select (case when Action_Type in ('01', '02', '03') then 'Administrative'
             when Action_Type in ('04') then 'User'
             when Action_Type in ('05', '06') then 'View-Only'
             else 'Unknown'
        end) as Action_Group, count(*), max(date)
from actions a
group by (case when Action_Type in ('01', '02', '03') then 'Administrative'
               when Action_Type in ('04') then 'User'
               when Action_Type in ('05', '06') then 'View-Only'
               else 'Unknown'
          end) ;
```

I would advise you, however, to create a reference table for action types that include the grouping that you want (if you don't already have such a table).